# How can I play a youtube video in windows media player?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube, google-api

I have already in the form1 design a windows media player control.
And this is how I'm getting my videos list and add them to a listBox:

```
static List<string> videosList = new List<string>();
        public async void RetrieveUploadsList()
        {
            UserCredentials();
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;
            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
            {
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

                Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null)
                {
                    var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
                    var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                    {
                            videosList.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                            listBox1.Items.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.PublishedAt);
                    }
                    nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
            }
            if (this.listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

No what I have is in the listBox all my videos list and the first item selected already. Once the first item is selected I want to show in the windows media player the selected item video first image(frame) like in youtube that you see the first image(frame) and them make play to start it.

And also to make that when I click on the windows media player play button it will play the video. (Do I need to download the video first? Or it will play it from the internet from youtube?)

The windows media player variable is:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1
```

How can I make this two things?

Comment: first you'd have to define what "youtube video" is. mp4? flv?

Comment: mp4 in this case. At least my videos uploaded on youtube are all mp4.

Comment: Ok i found how to do it. First i'm building a string with the video url: Url = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId i removed from the url the "watch?" and "=" and then i assign the url to the windows media player: axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[80];

Comment: Marc B why does it matter if the youtube video is mp4 or flv ?

Comment: Marc B you right windows media player can't play flv videos. Is there any other way then to play the videos from youtube on winforms ?